# ant delete task gives error

Tags: ant

I want delete a directory only if exists.

```
 <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${COMP_BUILD}" />
    </target>
```

this gets error

```
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory U:\id824275_03_2011_06_JUN_ESW\CCS_WSC_ECM\ecm_esw\app\ENT_APP\ESW\bgc-esw-services\build

BUILD FAILED
U:\id824275_03_2011_06_JUN_ESW\CCS_WSC_ECM\ecm_esw\app\BUILD\ESW\ESWBUILD\build.xml:451: The following error occurred while executing this line:
U:\id824275_03_2011_06_JUN_ESW\CCS_WSC_ECM\ecm_esw\app\ENT_APP\ESW\bgc-esw-web\build.xml:207: The following error occurred while executing this line:
U:\id824275_03_2011_06_JUN_ESW\CCS_WSC_ECM\ecm_esw\app\ENT_APP\ESW\bgc-esw-web\build.xml:84: The following error occurred while executing this line:
U:\id824275_03_2011_06_JUN_ESW\CCS_WSC_ECM\ecm_esw\app\ENT_APP\ESW\bgc-esw-services\build.xml:64: Unable to delete directory U:\id824275_03_2011_06_JUN_ESW\CCS_WSC_ECM\ecm_esw\app\ENT_APP\ESW\bgc-esw-services\build\lib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify `failonerror`:

```
<delete dir="${COMP_BUILD}" failonerror="false"/>
```

This will continue execution if the directory doesn't exist.

The trouble with this is that if the directory *does* exist, but can't be deleted for some other reason, then it will also still carry on.